# Dealing with two different types in RxJava's .flatMap() operator

Tags: java, rx-java, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java2

The application i'm writing performs an initial API call with Retrofit which returns a URL. That response is then `.flatMap`'d into another API call depending on the text contained in the URL. However, the two secondary API calls are defined to return different response models.

To make things clearer, here is some code:

```
APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

service.getURL() // returns response model containing a URL.                                                                                                                                                                                  
.flatMap(new Function<GetURLResponse, ObservableSource<?>>() {                                                       
    @Override                                                                                                            
    public ObservableSource<?> apply(GetURLResponse getURLResponse) throws Exception {                           

        // Determine whether the returned url is for "first.com".                                       
        if (getURLResponse.url.contains("first.com")) {                                    
            return service.first(getURLResponse.url);                                                                                   
        }                                                                                                                

        // Otherwise, the URL is not for "first.com", so use our other service method.                                                         
        return service.second(getURLResponse.url);                                    
    }                                                                                                                    
})
```

Here are the interface definitions for `service.first()` and `service.second()`:

```
@GET                                                                                    
Observable<retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody>> first(@Url String url);                    

@GET                                                                                    
Observable<SecondModel> second(@Url String url);
```

How can I better handle these two different possible types (`retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody>` and `SecondModel`) for the rest of the stream? Eg. If the initial URL contains `first.com` then the `service.first()` API call should fire, and operators down the stream should received a `retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody>`. Conversely, if the initial URL does *not* contain `first.com`, the `service.second()` API call should fire and operators down the stream should receive a `SecondModel`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to have both your model classes implement an interface and return that interface, alternatively the models could both extend an abstract class to achieve the same effect. You would then do an `instanceOf` check to see which model it is and continue with your preferred transformations.

That having said you mentioning downstream operators, makes me think that this would cause an annoying amount of checks. So what I would do is split the stream using the `publish` operator, and then apply your further transformations to each sub-stream. Finally you should merge the two streams back together and return a single model encompassing both models.

Below a code example to get you started.

```
Observable<Integer> fooObservableSecondaryRequest(String foo) {
    return Observable.just(1);
}
Observable<Integer> booObservableSecondaryRequest(String boo) {
    return Observable.just(2);
}
Observable<String> stringObservable = Observable.just("foo", "boo");

stringObservable.publish(shared -> Observable.merge(
            shared.filter(a -> a.equals("foo"))
                    .flatMap(fooString -> fooObservableSecondaryRequest(fooString))
                    .map(num -> num * 2),
            shared.filter(a -> a.equals("boo"))
                    .flatMap(booString -> booObservableSecondaryRequest(booString))
                    .map(num -> num * 10)
    )).subscribe(result -> System.out.println(result)); // will print 2 and 20
```

Comment: One of the responses returns a third party type (`Response<ResponseBody>`) so I cannot have both return models inherit from the same super. How would `.publish` work if `fooObservableSecondaryRequest` returned an `Observable<String>` instead?

Comment: Remember a `ResponseBody` response is just a raw response. Meaning it didn't get marshaled for you using a GsonConverter or any of the other converters you may have chosen to use with Retrofit.  But the value returned by this Observable has nothing to do with the value returned by the composed Observable. For example if we would change `fooObservableSecondaryRequest` to return an `Observable<String>` then all we would have to do is add a simple mapping to convert it to the encompassing type. In the simple example this would be `.map(stringResposne -> Integer.valueOf(stringResponse))`.